# pandas df.at utterly slow in some lines

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, numpy, jupyter-notebook

I've got a .txt logfile with IMU sensor measurements which need to be parsed to a .CSV file. Accelerometer, gyroscope have 500Hz ODR (output data rate) magnetomer 100Hz, gps 1Hz and baro 1Hz. Wi-fi, BLE, pressure, light etc. is also logged but most is not needed. The smartphone App doesn't save all measurements sequentially.

It takes 1000+ seconds to parse a file of 200k+ lines to a pandas DataFrame sort the DataFrame on the timestamps and save it as a csv file.

When assigning values of sensor measurements at a coordinate (Row=Timestamp, column=sensor measurement) in the DataFrame, some need ~40% of the runtime, while others take +- 0.1% of the runtime.

What could be the reason for this? 
It shouldn't take a 1000+ seconds..

---

#### What is in the logfile:

```
ACCE;AppTimestamp(s);SensorTimestamp(s);Acc_X(m/s^2);Acc_Y(m/s^2);Acc_Z(m/s^2);Accuracy(integer)
GYRO;AppTimestamp(s);SensorTimestamp(s);Gyr_X(rad/s);Gyr_Y(rad/s);Gyr_Z(rad/s);Accuracy(integer)
MAGN;AppTimestamp(s);SensorTimestamp(s);Mag_X(uT);;Mag_Y(uT);Mag_Z(uT);Accuracy(integer)
MAGN;AppTimestamp(s);SensorTimestamp(s);Mag_X(uT);;Mag_Y(uT);Mag_Z(uT);Accuracy(integer)
PRES;AppTimestamp(s);SensorTimestamp(s);Pres(mbar);Accuracy(integer)
LIGH;AppTimestamp(s);SensorTimestamp(s);Light(lux);Accuracy(integer)
PROX;AppTimestamp(s);SensorTimestamp(s);prox(?);Accuracy(integer)
HUMI;AppTimestamp(s);SensorTimestamp(s);humi(Percentage);Accuracy(integer)
TEMP;AppTimestamp(s);SensorTimestamp(s);temp(Celsius);Accuracy(integer)
AHRS;AppTimestamp(s);SensorTimestamp(s);PitchX(deg);RollY(deg);YawZ(deg);RotVecX();RotVecY();RotVecZ();Accuracy(int)
GNSS;AppTimestamp(s);SensorTimeStamp(s);Latit(deg);Long(deg);Altitude(m);Bearing(deg);Accuracy(m);Speed(m/s);SatInView;SatInUse
WIFI;AppTimestamp(s);SensorTimeStamp(s);Name_SSID;MAC_BSSID;RSS(dBm);
BLUE;AppTimestamp(s);Name;MAC_Address;RSS(dBm);
BLE4;AppTimestamp(s);MajorID;MinorID;RSS(dBm);
SOUN;AppTimestamp(s);RMS;Pressure(Pa);SPL(dB);
RFID;AppTimestamp(s);ReaderNumber(int);TagID(int);RSS_A(dBm);RSS_B(dBm);
IMUX;AppTimestamp(s);SensorTimestamp(s);Counter;Acc_X(m/s^2);Acc_Y(m/s^2);Acc_Z(m/s^2);Gyr_X(rad/s);Gyr_Y(rad/s);Gyr_Z(rad/s);Mag_X(uT);;Mag_Y(uT);Mag_Z(uT);Roll(deg);Pitch(deg);Yaw(deg);Quat(1);Quat(2);Quat(3);Quat(4);Pressure(mbar);Temp(Celsius)
IMUL;AppTimestamp(s);SensorTimestamp(s);Counter;Acc_X(m/s^2);Acc_Y(m/s^2);Acc_Z(m/s^2);Gyr_X(rad/s);Gyr_Y(rad/s);Gyr_Z(rad/s);Mag_X(uT);;Mag_Y(uT);Mag_Z(uT);Roll(deg);Pitch(deg);Yaw(deg);Quat(1);Quat(2);Quat(3);Quat(4);Pressure(mbar);Temp(Celsius)
POSI;Timestamp(s);Counter;Latitude(degrees); Longitude(degrees);floor ID(0,1,2..4);Building ID(0,1,2..3)
```

#### A part of the RAW .txt logfile:

```
MAGN;1.249;343268.933;2.64000;-97.50000;-69.06000;0
GYRO;1.249;343268.934;0.02153;0.06943;0.09880;3
ACCE;1.249;343268.934;-0.24900;0.53871;9.59625;3 GNSS;1.250;1570711878.000;52.225976;5.174543;58.066;175.336;3.0;0.0;23;20
ACCE;1.253;343268.936;-0.26576;0.52674;9.58428;3
GYRO;1.253;343268.936;0.00809;0.06515;0.10002;3
ACCE;1.253;343268.938;-0.29450;0.49561;9.57710;3
GYRO;1.253;343268.938;0.00015;0.06088;0.10613;3
PRES;1.253;343268.929;1011.8713;3
GNSS;1.254;1570711878.000;52.225976;5.174543;58.066;175.336;3.0;0.0;23;20
ACCE;1.255;343268.940;-0.29450;0.49801;9.57710;3
GYRO;1.255;343268.940;-0.00596;0.05843;0.10979;3
ACCE;1.260;343268.942;-0.30647;0.50280;9.55795;3
GYRO;1.261;343268.942;-0.01818;0.05721;0.11529;3
MAGN;1.262;343268.943;2.94000;-97.74000;-68.88000;0
```

---

fileContent are the strings of the txt file as showed above.

#### Piece of the code:

```
def parseValues(line):
    valArr = []
    valArr = np.fromstring(line[5:], dtype=float, sep=";")

    return (valArr)

i = 0
while i < len(fileContent):
    if (fileContent[i][:4] == "ACCE"):
        vals = parseValues(fileContent[i])
        idx = vals[1] - initialSensTS
        df.at[idx, 'ax'] = vals[2]
        df.at[idx, 'ay'] = vals[3]
        df.at[idx, 'az'] = vals[4]
        df.at[idx, 'accStat'] = vals[5]
        i += 1
```

---

The code works, but it's utterly slow at some of the df.at[idx, 'xx'] lines.

See Line # 28.

#### Line profiler output:

```
Line #      Hits         Time  Per Hit   % Time  Line Contents
==============================================================
22         1          1.0      1.0      0.0      i = 0
23    232250     542594.0      2.3      0.0      while i < len(fileContent):
24    232249  294337000.0   1267.3     23.8          update_progress(i / len(fileContent))
25    232249     918442.0      4.0      0.1          if (fileContent[i][:4] == "ACCE"):
26     54602    1584625.0     29.0      0.1              vals = parseValues(fileContent[i])
27     54602     316968.0      5.8      0.0              idx = vals[1] - initialSensTS
28     54602  504189480.0   9233.9     40.8              df.at[idx, 'ax'] = vals[2]
29     54602    8311109.0    152.2      0.7              df.at[idx, 'ay'] = vals[3]
30     54602    4901983.0     89.8      0.4              df.at[idx, 'az'] = vals[4]
31     54602    4428239.0     81.1      0.4              df.at[idx, 'accStat'] = vals[5]
32     54602     132590.0      2.4      0.0              i += 1
```

Comment: What is the issue with using the built in `I/O` tools of pandas to just read this file into a DataFrame from the start?

Comment: pd.read_csv is giving `ParserError: Error tokenizing data. ` because the GNSS rows do not have the same amount of columns compared to ACCE, GYRO etc.

Comment: How about something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55189021/3282436)?

Comment: I'll second the suggestions in the link that @0x5453 shared, particularly this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/55189021/11301900.

Comment: A few notes: Variables should generally follow the `lower_case_with_underscores` style, not `camelCase`. I see no reason to use numpy to parse a string into an array, and then manually index that array to retrieve the elements. If I understand your `while` loop correctly, it only increments when `fileContent[i][:4] == "ACCE"`. If `fileContent[i][:4] != "ACCE"`, the counter does not change, which means that `fileContent[i][:4]` _still_ isn't equal to `"ACCE"`. The result should be an infinite loop, no? I don't understand why you aren't iterating over the file contents with a `for` loop.

Comment: I tried a few things out with your data, and I'm starting to suspect that pandas may not be the tool for the job.

Comment: Or not, sorry. I may have found something viable. I'm exhausted though, so I will only be able to post an answer tomorrow.

Comment: I hadn't noticed earlier, but some example output would be nice.

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't address the part of your question about sorting timestamps etc, but should be an efficient replacement for your `'ACCE'` parsing code.

```py
import pandas as pd
import collections as colls

logs_file_path = '../resources/imu_logs_raw.txt'

msmt_type_dict = colls.defaultdict(list)

with open(logs_file_path, 'r') as file_1:
    for line in file_1:
        curr_measure_type, *rest_str = line.split(';')
        rest_str[-1] = rest_str[-1].strip()
        msmt_type_dict[curr_measure_type].append(rest_str)

acce_df = pd.DataFrame(data=msmt_type_dict['ACCE'], columns=['app_timestamp', 'sensor_timestamp', 'acc_x', 'acc_y', 'acc_z', 'accuracy'])
```

If you can provide some more information/context I would love to take a look at the timestamp sorting aspect.