# use regex to extract data to dataframe

Tags: python, regex, pandas, jupyter-notebook

i have a log

```
20201006T153833.159+0200 0243 request.log,
20201006T153833.159+0200 0244 request.ESelection,
20201006T153833.159+0200 0245 request.DateOn,   Assure.dateDeNaissance,

20201006T153833.159+0200 0289 Gestion, request.ESelection, request.ESelectionGestion, SelectionReference
```

and desired output is:

```
Date                       Number                 Request1               Request2               Request3               

20201006T153833.159+0200    0243      request.log

20201006T153833.159+0200    0244      request.ESelection
20201006T153833.159+0200    0245      request.DateOn           Assure.dateDeNaissance,

20201006T153833.159+0200    0289      Gestion,                 request.ESelection            SelectionReference
```

i tried this

df = pd.read_table("request.log",
sep=r'^([\d+]+? [\d:]+?) ',header= None
)

Anyone help?

Comment: You can do something similar like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55129746/5302442)
`pd.read_table('test.log', sep='\n', header=None)[0].str.split(' ', expand=True)`

Answer (score 0):

Best I can do is reading the lines one by one, accumulating a dictionary for each line and finally forming the DataFrame

```
logs = open('log_data.txt', 'r') 
lines = logs.readlines()

data_dict = []
for line in lines:
    curr_dict = {}
    line_split = line.split()
    curr_dict['Date'], curr_dict['Number'] = line_split[0], line_split[1]
    for i in range(2, len(line_split)):
        curr_dict['Request' + str(i-1)] = line_split[i]
    data_dict.append(curr_dict)
data = pd.DataFrame(data_dict)
```