# pandas read_csv() fails reading file from gdrive but succeeds reading same downloaded file

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I'm trying to read a CSV file from gdrive to a pandas dataframe using `pd.read_csv()`:

```
b_merge = pd.read_csv(
    "https://drive.google.com/file/d/some_file_id",
    low_memory=False
)
```

but I'm getting the following error:

```
ParserError: Error tokenizing data. C error: Expected 90 fields in line 3, saw 217
```

If I download the file to my local drive, it can be read by `pd.read_csv()` with no problem at all.

I tried some of [these alternatives](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18039057/python-pandas-error-tokenizing-data), but they don't work (skipping lines is not an option)

Comment: Hi, does this help: https://stackoverflow.com/a/55129746/11246056?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Read CSV into a dataFrame with varying row lengths using Pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55129640/read-csv-into-a-dataframe-with-varying-row-lengths-using-pandas)